# Force y axis to start at 0 and still use automated labeling

Tags: plot, label, stata, axis-labels, yaxis

I have a plot whose y min starts well above 0. But I want to include 0 as the min of the y-axis and still have Stata *automatically* create evenly-spaced y-axis labels.

Here is the baseline:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
scatter turn displacement
```

This produces:
[image]

This is almost what I want, except that the y range does not start at 0.

Based on this answer by Nick Cox (https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1598753-force-chart-y-axis-to-start-at-0), I modify the code to be:

```
scatter turn displacement, yscale(range(0 .)) ylabel(0)
```

This succeeds in starting the y-axis at 0, but the labeling besides 0 goes away:

[image]

I proceed to remove `ylabel(0):

```
scatter turn displacement, yscale(range(0 .))
```

This produces the opposite problem - the y-axis labels are the same as in the first plot.

How can I have Stata automatically produce the y-axis labels from 0 to the max? For instance, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 - importantly, though, I have many plots and need a solution that determines the exact values automatically, without needing me to input the y max, etc. So it would not be me who chooses 10, 20, ..., 50, but Stata.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By coincidence, I have been working on a command in this territory. Here is a reproducible example.

```
sysuse auto, clear
summarize turn, meanonly
local max = r(max) 
nicelabels 0 `max', local(yla)
* shows 0 20 40 60
scatter turn displacement, yla(`yla', ang(h))
nicelabels 0 `max', local(yla) nvals(10)
* shows 0 10 20 30 40 50 60
scatter turn displacement, yla(`yla', ang(h))
```

where `nicelabels` is at present this code.

```
*! 1.0.0 NJC 25 April 2022 
program nicelabels           
    /// fudge() undocumented 
    version 9

    gettoken first 0 : 0, parse(" ,")  

    capture confirm numeric variable `first' 

    if _rc == 0 {
        // syntax varname(numeric), Local(str) [ nvals(int 5) tight Fudge(real 0) ] 

        syntax [if] [in] , Local(str) [ nvals(int 5) tight Fudge(real 0) ] 
        local varlist `first'  

        marksample touse 
        quietly count if `touse'    
        if r(N) == 0 exit 2000 
    } 
    else { 
        // syntax #1 #2 , Local(str) [ nvals(int 5) tight Fudge(real 0) ] 

        confirm number `first' 
        gettoken second 0 : 0, parse(" ,") 
        syntax , Local(str) [ nvals(int 5) tight Fudge(real 0) ]
 
        if _N < 2 { 
            preserve 
            quietly set obs 2 
        }
    
        tempvar varlist touse 
        gen double `varlist' = cond(_n == 1, `first', `second') 
        gen byte `touse' = _n <= 2 
    }   

    su `varlist' if `touse', meanonly
    local min = r(min) - (r(max) - r(min)) * `fudge'/100 
    local max = r(max) + (r(max) - r(min)) * `fudge'/100 
 
    local tight = "`tight'" == "tight"
    mata: nicelabels(`min', `max', `nvals', `tight') 

    di "`results'"
    c_local `local' "`results'"
end  

mata : 

void nicelabels(real min, real max, real nvals, real tight) { 
    if (min == max) {
        st_local("results", min) 
        exit(0) 
    }

    real range, d, newmin, newmax
    colvector nicevals 
    range = nicenum(max - min, 0) 
    d = nicenum(range / (nvals - 1), 1)
    newmin = tight == 0 ? d * floor(min / d) : d * ceil(min / d)
    newmax = tight == 0 ? d * ceil(max / d) : d * floor(max / d)  
    nvals = 1 + (newmax - newmin) / d 
    nicevals = newmin :+ (0 :: nvals - 1) :* d  
    st_local("results", invtokens(strofreal(nicevals')))   
}

real nicenum(real x, real round) { 
    real expt, f, nf 
    
    expt = floor(log10(x)) 
    f = x / (10^expt) 
    
    if (round) { 
        if (f < 1.5) nf = 1 
        else if (f < 3) nf = 2
        else if (f < 7) nf = 5
        else nf = 10 
    }
    else { 
        if (f <= 1) nf = 1 
        else if (f <= 2) nf = 2 
        else if (f <= 5) nf = 5 
        else nf = 10 
    }

    return(nf * 10^expt)
}

end
```

EDIT

If you go

```
sysuse auto, clear 
summarize turn, meanonly 
local max = r(max) 
scatter turn displacement, yla(0(10)`max', ang(h))
scatter turn displacement, yla(0(20)`max', ang(h))
```

you get good solutions. Clearly in this case we need to know that 10 or 20 is a step size to use. There would be scope to calculate a good width programmatically using your own recipe.

EDIT 10 May 2022

A revised and documented `nicelabels` is now downloadable from SSC.

EDIT 2 28 Sept 2023 A write-up is now accessible [in this *Stata Journal* paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X221141058).

Comment: I also found this solution:  `ylabel(#6) yscale(range(0 .))`. I am curious to know the difference.

Comment: Evidently if you change the axis range that in itself does not vary the labels shown. But if you specify a different label specification, `graph` takes account of the axis range.  My command doesn't rule out other solutions, which would be better if they just used official code.  Please see latest EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

Nick's solution is better, but a **crude** and simple solution is to plot another series that is at or near 0, and it could be invisible. For example:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
gen zero = 0 
twoway (scatter turn displacement) ///
       (scatter zero displacement , mcolor(none) ) , ///
       legend(off)                                       /* or legend(order(1))   */
```

But care would need to be taken of the legend.